# How to break all reference loops between DOM and JavaScript in IE8 to allow memory be reclaimed?

Tags: javascript, iframe, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to get rid of memory leak in IE8, caused by reference loops between event handlers and DOM elements during iframe navigation. I can not modify other scripts on the page.

So the idea was to walk through the DOM and window object and nullify all fields to ensure no DOM element references event handler.

Now the problem is I need to do it after all other unload handlers are run, because other handlers might depend on fields I'm going to nullify.

I tried to do store document object before navigation somewhere in parent window, and then, after navigation in my iframe completes (onload event), run cleanup on stored document object. However, apparently, you can't do it, because after old page is unloaded accessing this document becomes illegal (access error).

The other approach I tried was to find way to add window unload handler, which will be guaranteed to be called the last, however, I did not successed in it so far. To achieve that I tried to call all handlers for the unload event, clean them, and than run my code, but I did not found a way to trigger unload event manually.

Any ideas? Unfortunately, page uses jQuery and Microsoft Ajax, which have their own unload handlers. In particular, my nullification breaks MS Ajax unload handler, because it removes all library namespaces.

Comment: What evidence do you have of memory leaks? How are they being caused (specifically)?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to guarantee the removal of all event listeners if you don't know how they were attached in the first place.

IE 8 uses *attachEvent*, so if a listener is added like:

```
element.attachEvent('onclick', function(){...});
```

then you have no way of knowing that the listener is attached. Setting the *onclick* property to some new value (say '') will not remove the listener, nor will adding another by *attachEvent*. In DOM compliant browsers, replacing an element with a clone of itself will remove listeners, but not in IE where *attachEVent* has been used.

Strategies for avoiding memory leaks usually involve not creating circular references involving DOM elements.

Strategies for removing all listeners generally rely on keeping a list of what's been added, then explicitly removing them before the page unloads.

Both can be difficult and are impossible to guarantee if you don't have control of all code in the page.